# Stored procedure won't show up when creating table adapter

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 2 stored procedures in my database. I'm trying to create a Table Adapter that uses them. I click on "Use existing stored procedure", but no stored procedures show up in the next step!

Answer (score 0):

I did not have the correct permissions for my database set. Permissions for a database can be set in server management studio, right click on you DB, select properties, select permissions, select a role and grant the necessary permissions.